# Convert List<MyObject> to Dictionary <obj.string, List<obj.ID>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would like to take a list of objects and convert it to a dictionary where the key is a field in the object, and the value is a list of a different field in the objects that match on the key. I can do this now with a loop but I feel this should be able to be accomplished with linq and not having to write the loop. I was thinking a combination of `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` but have been unsuccessful so far.

Here's how I'm doing it right now:

```
var samplesWithSpecificResult = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
foreach(var sample in sampleList)
{
    List<int> sampleIDs = null;
    if (samplesWithSpecificResult.TryGetValue(sample.ResultString, out sampleIDs))
    {
        sampleIDs.Add(sample.ID);
        continue;
    }
    sampleIDs = new List<int>();
    sampleIDs.Add(sample.ID);
    samplesWithSpecificResult.Add(sample.ResultString, sampleIDs);
}
```

The farthest I can get with `.GroupBy().ToDictionay()` is  `Dictionary<sample.ResultString, List<sample>>`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Learn to love the [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try the following

```
var dictionary = sampleList
    .GroupBy(x => x.ResultString, x => x.ID)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

The `GroupBy` clause will group every `Sample` instance in the list by its `ResultString` member, but it will keep only the `Id` part of each sample.  This means every element will be an [`IGrouping<string, int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `ToDictionary` portion uses the `Key` of the `IGrouping<string, int>` as the dictionary Key. `IGrouping<string, int>` implements `IEnumerable<int>` and hence we can convert that collection of samples' `Id` to a `List<int>` with a call to `ToList`, which becomes the `Value` of the dictionary for that given `Key`.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! Figure out those details by trial and error would take some time.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, super simple. The key is that when you do a `GroupBy` on `IEnumerable<T>`, each "group" is an object that implements `IEnumerable<T>` as well (that's why I can say `g.Select` below, and I'm projecting the elements of the original sequence with a common key):

```
var dictionary =
     sampleList.GroupBy(x => x.ResultString)
               .ToDictionary(
                   g => g.Key,
                   g => g.Select(x => x.ID).ToList()
     );
```

See, the result of `sampleList.GroupBy(x => x.ResultString)` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Sample>>` and `IGrouping<T, U>` implements `IEnumerable<U>` so that every group *is* a sequence of `Sample` with the common key!

Answer (score 3):

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> resultDictionary = 
(
  from sample in sampleList
  group sample.ID by sample.ResultString
).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

You might want to consider using a Lookup instead of the Dictionary of Lists

```
ILookup<string, int> idLookup = sampleList.ToLookup(
  sample => sample.ResultString,
  sample => sample.ID
);
```

used thusly

```
foreach(IGrouping<string, int> group in idLookup)
{
  string resultString = group.Key;
  List<int> ids = group.ToList();
  //do something with them.
}

//and

List<int> ids = idLookup[resultString].ToList();
```

Comment: The Lookup is a good idea and something I'll definitely play around with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
var samplesWithSpecificResult =
    sampleList.GroupBy(s => s.ResultString)
              .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(s => s.ID).ToList());
```

What we 're doing here is group the samples based on their `ResultString` -- this puts them into an `IGrouping<string, Sample>`. Then we project the collection of `IGrouping`s to a dictionary, using the `Key` of each as the dictionary key and enumerating over each grouping (`IGrouping<string, Sample>` is also an `IEnumerable<Sample>`) to select the `ID` of each sample to make a list for the dictionary value.